# What are some good methods to push schema updates to end user databases?

Tags: sql, database, database-administration

This might be too broad, but it's a problem I'm having a bear of a time dealing with. We have an application that we distribute to our end users. It's running on top of a derby back end. We can push out code changes fairly easily, it'll go out to our server, see there's a new version, download, overwrite old code, and reboot.

But, as we change our code, we also alter the schema of the derby database. We don't have great methods to update this. Currently we can push SQL updates via FTP. When the program is connected to the internet, it looks for new SQL files, downloads them and runs.

Unfortunately a lot of our clients have limited Internet access, so they get these updates intermittently. Sometimes because they changes are big enough, their local DB schema gets out of sync with what we want. Or they get the code changes via CD but not the SQL changes (someone mails them the CD).

What I've been trying to do is create a SOAP service that can serve up XML representations of the schema. It's been a huge PITA to develop so far.

What are some methods people are currently using to maintain databases like this? I feel like I'm not the first to do this, so there might be better ways than what I'm doing.

**Based on some comments here, here's an update:**
Basically, I think we screwed ourselves early on by not adhering to a strict versioning of the DB, so I don't know how everyone's DB is at. A lot of people got custom installs built (groan at will). I need a tool that can tell the differences between their DB and a "official" copy.

I have a tool built, it kind of works, but there's so…many…things to keep track of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you distribute the DB changes as part of the code changes? Then, when the app restarts, it checks if it needs to run any updates on the DB.

Obviously, you'll need to version the DB schema to avoid applying the same update more than once.

I know some applications that do this (mostly in Ruby, but also in Java).

Comment: Ideally yes, but the issue is people have gotten code changes via CD's that were mailed, without SQL updates. So some people are kind of in this flux of we don't know what updates they need exactly. We were doing fixes one by one, but now with hundreds of users it's not an option.

Comment: I think you hit the issue of not versioning the schema, so now you don't know what patches your clients need. You could (potentially) write a script that detects which is the version of the schema (e.g. if x column exist, then the version is at least 1.3), and from there run the process that updates the schema. What I'm trying to say is that whatever solution you find, you might really, want to start versioning the schema to prevent this from hapenning again.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an update mechanism in place in your application that can download a program to alter the installed source code, why not package and run the schema changes as a part of that upgrade process? I would just run the updates as a part of the Java application then.

My team at work handles these changes by using the [MyBatis Migration tool](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Migration), which represents each schema change as a single migration script which contains the "make change" and "rollback" steps. A `changelog` table is stored in the database which lists which updates have been applied to that database, which makes it easy for the `migrate` command to determine which updates it needs to apply when run. This specific tool is probably only really useful when you control the database and have the ability to run shell commands and scripts to alter the database, but you can use the same concepts in your approach - package each schema change as an atomic unit and run them from within your program to bring the schema up to the current version, which you can track in the db itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a table containing the version of the database that the user is running, and then you'll need code to upgrade from version n to version n+1. Assuming you have a database user that has access to do schema changes, you can apply schema changes the same way you're now applying code changes.